# Let cider-scratch evaluate in Clojurescript REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider

Is there a way to let the cider-scratch buffer compile against a clojure-script repl? The default is that the evaluations are sent to a clojure repl inside Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible at present.  I've opened an issue for you over [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/1789).